# Invoke WLST commands with JSch

Tags: java, ssh, weblogic, jsch, wlst

I'm trying to run a restart server command on WLST through a remote Java web app.

This is what I'm trying to execute:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("/u01/app/oracle/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/./java -cp /u01/app/oracle/product/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.WLST");
sb.append(";connect(\'weblogic\',\'" + consolePass + "\',\'" + fullAddress + "\')");
sb.append(";domainRuntime()");
sb.append(";cd(\'/ServerLifeCycleRuntimes/" + serverName + "\')");
sb.append(";cmo.shutdown())");
sb.append(";start(" + serverName + ",'Server')");
String command = sb.toString();

JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
session.setUserInfo(new OracleUserInfo(pass));
session.connect();

Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
channel.setInputStream(null);
((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
channel.connect();

byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
while (true) {
    while (in.available() > 0) {
        int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
        if (i < 0)
            break;
        System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
    }
    if (channel.isClosed()) {
        if (in.available() > 0)
            continue;
        System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
        break;
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception ee) {
    }
}
channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
```

I'm using ';' to separate the commands, since I thought it was required to run multiple commands.

Unfortunately, it gives a syntax error on line 2.

> bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `'weblogic','password','t3://host:7001''
>
>   bash: -c: line 0:`/u01/app/oracle/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/./java -cp /u01/app/oracle/product/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.WLST;connect('weblogic','password','t3://host:7001')'

I tried to add `\n` after the first line, and the result was that the first line was executed (so it entered WLST), but none of the remaining commands were.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("/u01/app/oracle/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/./java -cp /u01/app/oracle/product/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.WLST\n");
sb.append(";connect(\'weblogic\',\'" + consolePass + "\',\'" + fullAddress + "\')\n");
sb.append(";domainRuntime()\n");
sb.append(";cd(\'/ServerLifeCycleRuntimes/" + serverName + "\')\n");
sb.append(";cmo.shutdown())\n");
String command = sb.toString();
```

Result:

> Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
>   Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell
>       Type help() for help on available commands
>      wls:/offline>

I tested the command manually and it worked. The problem seems to be with JSch with WLST interface, since it opens another shell interface.

Any ideas how I could run WLST commands with JSch?

PS1: I know my JSch code works because I have a feature on the same app to deploy. Basically, it runs a jscp to upload the war, and then ssh to execute the weblogic.Deployer -deploy command.

PS2: I do have a .py script to do that, but as of now, it must be on the server to be executed. I'm thinking about doing an jscp to a temp folder, run the script and then delete. But I'm curious to find out how to run multiple commands on WLST with JSch.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Code working (Thanks Martin)

```
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);

    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
    channel.connect();
    for (String wlstCommand : wlstCommands) {
        out.write((wlstCommand).getBytes());
    }
    out.flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `;` can indeed by used in *nix based system to execute multiple commands in one shell command-line.

But what you are executing are not shell commands. Those are WLST commands, right? So you have to feed them to WLST.

Like this:

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("java -cp /.../weblogic.jar weblogic.WLST");
OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
channel.connect();
out.write(("connect('weblogic'...)\n").getBytes());
out.write(("domainRuntime()\n").getBytes());
...
```

---

It's basically the same as generic [Providing input/subcommands to command executed over SSH with JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42997422/850848).