# Provide inputs to individual prompts separately with JSch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

The problem is that the SSH connection requires the provision of another userid and password info after the general log in.

I am using JSch to connect to the remote server. It takes input in the form of a `InputStream`. And this `InputStream` can only be passed once. This causes problems as the session is interactive.

I've tried passing the input stream as linefeed separate values (`"username\npassword\n"`). This however does not work. Any suggestions would be welcome. Even if I have to look for a new Java library altogether.

```
try {
    JSch jsch=new JSch();
    Session session=jsch.getSession( "username1", "host", 22);
    session.setPassword("password1");
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.connect(30000);
    Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");           
    String data = "username2\npassword2\n";
    channel.setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes()));
    channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
    channel.connect(3*1000);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The password is not entered properly and it does not navigate to the next set of instruction displayed by the ssh connection.

However, if I try the same with the system console (`System.in`) as the input stream, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it looks like the password is provided too quickly and the way the server is implemented, it discards the input that comes too early (before a prompt).

You may need to wait before sending the password.

```
channel.connect();
OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
out.write(("username2\n").getBytes());
out.flush();   
Thread.sleep(1000); 
out.write(("password2\n").getBytes());
out.flush();
```

---

A more advanced solution would be to implement an [Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)-like functionality.